# File based routing in NodeJS/ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is there a way to do the following in NodeJS (or ExpressJS)?

While I understand the flexibility routing offers, I pretty much dislike the way it has to be configured. (I am no expert in Express)

For example, the application structure is as shown below:

```
app
-- public // has all the static files.
-- dynamic // Root level file for something that contains all the dynamic pages 
   -- index.nsf // NSF == node server file (Just making up a sample extension here).
                // NSF files have front matter and code like shown in section below
   -- posts // A directory
      -- view.nsf
      -- edit.nsf
   -- pages
      -- thankyou.nsf
      -- contactus.nsf
```

i.e when the user goes to the url "http://mydomain.com/pages/contactus", the content from that nsf file is rendered.

The NSF that I have in mind, will probably look like below - with just some YAML front matter

```
---
controller: contactUsController // A javascript file
layout: contact // Jade layout or HTML layouts
---
```

OR with some YAML front matter and layout as the content of the file.

```
---
controller: contactUsController
---
extends base
h1 This is the contact us page. Fill in the details below.
```

Even a one time configuration to setup a middleware like below would work:

```
app.use(app.**some_automatic_router**);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like this :

https://npmjs.org/package/dynamic-routes